# How do I refrence the current instance's form not refering to the root form?

Tags: delphi

I started more instances of the same form using:

```
var
  myForms: TArray<TTestForm>;
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(myForms, 10);
  for I:= 0 to 1 do begin
    myForms[I] := TTestForm.Create(Application);  // Application will free the forms on exit
    myForms[I].Caption:=inttostr(i);
    myForms[I].Show;
  end;
```

But when I have to modify one of the form's value from itself it will modify the value of the root form instead of itself.

Like I run `TestForm.Caption:='Test'` from one of the many form instances, instead of modifying itself it modifies the parent instance of "TestForm".

It there a way to reference the form from which the code is running on? Like the way you can always reference the main form using Application.MainForm.

Comment: In a method of the form, just write `Caption := 'Test'` which is the same thing as `Self.Caption := 'Test'``.

Comment: Yes, replace `TestForm.` with `Self.`, or simply omit it entirely